# How to count the number of times internet connectivity change in a android application

Tags: android, connectivity

I am able to detect whether the application is connected to WiFi or mobile network.But I am not able to log the number of times  the internet connection changes from Wifi to mobile network or vice versa.To log the network change do i need to check whether it is connected to WiFi or mobile.Then later how i need to check that application connected from WiFi to Mobile or vice versa?

I want to count the number of times the internet connectivity changes that occur in a android application.

The code snippet I have written is 
{
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

```
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    SharedPreferences pref =this.getApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences("network_change_count", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int count = pref.getInt("networkchange", 0);
    pref.edit().putInt("networkchange", ++count).apply();
       // return pref.getInt("networkchange", count);
    }
```

}
}

I have registered the receiver in the manifest file.
But now I am getting nullPointerexception when i try to invoke get the shared preference value.

SharedPreferences pref =this.getApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences("network_change_count", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int connectivitychange=pref.getInt("networkchange", 0);

May i Know what is the mistake which I have done in this code?

Please give me Suggestions:)

Comment: Post something what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method.

```
registerReceiver(networkBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));
```

You will get call here once connectivity changed.

```
BroadcastReceiver networkBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        count++;
    }
};
```

Comment: can i get a link which expalins the above code clearly as i am a beginner i cannot understand so easily

Comment: refer this. hope it helps http://www.androhub.com/android-detect-internet-connection-using-broadcast-receiver/

Comment: arshad   Where i need to include this statement  /*registerReceiver(networkBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"));*/

Comment: registerReceiver in onStart and unRegister in onStop

Comment: arshad i can use this register method in activity also ?  if i do this the count wil increase only once then later it comes out of loop

Comment: You can. Whenever the network change is detected, this method will call and the count will increase

Comment: arshad  here no need to write code to detect any change in network kn?

Comment: can we save the number of connectivity change in a shared preference?

Comment: Yes, you can save it

Comment: arshad why the value in shared preference is incrementing twice? what might be the problem?

Comment: Please debug and check it. May be you are missing something

Comment: SharedPreferences pref =context.getSharedPreferences("network_change_count", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor  editor=pref.edit();
            incrementedNetworkCount = incrementedNetworkCount+1;
            pref.edit().putInt("networkchange",incrementedNetworkCount).apply();
            editor.putInt("networkchange",incrementedNetworkCount);
            editor.commit();